# Gitlab private registry on Kubernetes - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I've self hosted instances of `Gitlab` and `Kubernetes`. I'm trying to integrate both tools to implements a CI/CD. I'm trying to configure privary registry of self hosted Gitlab in Kubernetes, but  when Pod is starting, it fails when trying to pull image from registry.

**Deployment.yml**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: ns-app
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: private-registry.gitlab.com/some-link/image:0.1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

**docker/config.json**

```json
{
  "auths":
    {
      "gitlab-registry.al.rn.leg.br":
        { 
            "username": "user",
            "password": "password"
        }
    }
}
```

**secrets.yml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: regcred
  namespace: ns-app
type: Opaque
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{docker/config.json in base64}}
```

Pod is getting **Forbidden 403** error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is wrong **type** attribute of **secrets.yml**.

It should be: **kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson**

Final file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: regcred
  namespace: ns-app
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{docker/config.json in base64}}
```